# Trigger Visual Studio Code Launch Program "Start Debugging" through terminal command

Tags: unix, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a `node.js` application and I am trying to create a `unix` way to trigger Visual Studio Code Launch Program through terminal.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/server.js",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted to chain the `terminal command` to this;

> npm run build && ?

Comment: It looksl ike you want to run your ` npm run build` as a `preLaunchTask`.  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes

Comment: @Mark oh, it looks like this is another method to go with. But what if I want to trigger the launch program as `terminal command`? Thanks for pointing another option.

Comment: You need to figure out the executable/binary of Visual Studio Code depending on the platform you are running this on (Windows? macOS?).